# Pages not rendering properly on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rendering

Hi I am in the midst of Ruby on Rails tutorial. MY pages are rendering perfectly on the localserver but NOT on Heroku. I have run the command "heroku run rake db:migrate". I also have gone through the Heroku logs. I am just not sure how to read them.

I am wondering if it has to do with my stylesheets but I replicated whatever was on my local server to github and heroku so not sure why it can't read it.

I am add a part of the logfile. I wish I could show snapshots but unfortunately I don't have rights to do so.

I would appreciate any help and tips on debugging this problem.

====logfile===========================================

2012-03-19T18:22:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

2012-03-19T18:22:43+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick

2012-03-19T18:22:43+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:36524

2012-03-19T18:22:43+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach

2012-03-19T18:22:43+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server

2012-03-19T18:22:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-19T18:22:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-19T18:22:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.81.36.121 at 2012-03-19 18:22:43 +0000

2012-03-19T18:22:44+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML

2012-03-19T18:22:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)

2012-03-19T18:22:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)

2012-03-19T18:22:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.9ms)

2012-03-19T18:22:44+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.5ms)

2012-03-19T18:22:44+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 75.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

2012-03-19T18:22:44+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss

2012-03-19T18:22:44+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-mist-1232.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=850ms status=304 bytes=0

2012-03-19T18:22:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing

2012-03-19T18:22:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created

2012-03-19T18:22:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting

2012-03-19T18:22:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM

2012-03-19T18:22:51+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-03-19 18:22:51] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM

2012-03-19T18:22:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'

2012-03-19T18:22:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 4160`

2012-03-19T18:22:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: "http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released." (called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2012-03-19T18:22:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: "http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released". (called from  at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2012-03-19T18:23:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2012-03-19T18:23:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> Process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM

2012-03-19T18:23:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

2012-03-19T18:23:04+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-03-19 18:23:04] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1

2012-03-19T18:23:04+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-03-19 18:23:04] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]

2012-03-19T18:23:04+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-03-19 18:23:04] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=4160

## 2012-03-19T18:23:05+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't mind but I took the liberty of going to your site myself to see what the problem is. The issue is that you're configuring to use the asset pipeline but none of your assets are compiled. You can verify this is the case by [visiting your main CSS file](https://stormy-mist-1232.herokuapp.com/assets/application-95bd4fe1de99c1cd91ec8e6f348a44bd.css) -- you'll notice there's nothing at all there.

This is likely because you forgot to include compilation directives at the top of your application.css. See [the asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for full details, but I bet you're missing a line like this at the top of your application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

Comment: Hi Veraticus thanks for doing so. I realised it when I did a view source that something was wrong with my asset pipeline because the CSS was empty. Unfortunately the relearning process means I have to spend hours on the easiest bugs. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! If I helped accept my answer; it'll make other people on Stack Overflow more likely to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before too, and I think it had something to do with precompiling your css file. Try going into config/environments/production.rb and add this `config.assets.precompile += [ "blueprint/*.css" ]`. I am assuming you're using the blueprint css file.

Comment: I will try this as well. Thanks for your response!